docker-compose run app の途中で発生するエラーが解決できない
実現したい事
docker-compose run app を最後まで実行したい。
現状
docker 初心者です。
今までは PHP + xampp や MAMP 等でローカル開発を行っていましたが、必要に迫られて ruby + docker の環境構築を試みています。
その環境構築中に docker-compose run app setup_once で発生するエラーで先に進めていません。
検索は色々としたのですが、解決には至らず、、
次に、実行環境や、関連ファイル、試したこと等を記載します。
Dockerfile、docker-compose.yml は別担当者が2022年より以前に作成したもので、本人にはすぐに確認できない状態です。
もし、何かお気づきの点がございましたらご指摘頂けますと、大変助かります。
実行環境
Windows 10 Pro
WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux)
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Docker Desktop for Windows

Dockefile
FROM ****/****-ruby-base:8 ****  ##サービス名関連の為、伏せてあります。


ARG RAILS_MASTER_KEY
ENV RAILS_MASTER_KEY=$RAILS_MASTER_KEY

ARG RAILS_ENV=development
ENV RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV

RUN mkdir -p /app/tmp/pids
WORKDIR /app

ADD Gemfile Gemfile.lock /app/

RUN bundle install --without test --deployment

COPY . /app

RUN ./bin/yarn
RUN ./bin/rails assets:precompile

docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.mysql.dev
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    command: bundle exec rails server --port=3000 --binding=0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:${PWD}
      - .:/app
      - bundle_install:/app/vendor/bundle
      - bundle:/app/.bundle
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
    environment:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    cap_add:
      - sys_admin
  worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:${PWD}
      - .:/app
      - bundle_install:/app/vendor/bundle
      - bundle:/app/.bundle
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
    environment:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:
  redis:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.redis.dev
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
  middlewares:
    image: alpine
    command: "echo run middlewares"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - redis
volumes:
  mysql-data:
    driver: local
  bundle_install:
    driver: local
  bundle:
    driver: local
  node_modules:
    driver: local

処理中断するエラー
....
#12 29.87 Preparing to unpack google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb ...
#12 29.88 Unpacking google-chrome-stable (126.0.6478.126-1) ...
#12 38.51 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
#12 38.51  google-chrome-stable depends on libu2f-udev; however:
#12 38.51   Package libu2f-udev is not installed.
#12 38.51  google-chrome-stable depends on libvulkan1; however:
#12 38.51   Package libvulkan1 is not installed.
#12 38.51
#12 38.51 dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--install):
#12 38.51  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
#12 38.51 Processing triggers for mime-support (3.62) ...
#12 38.56 Errors were encountered while processing:
#12 38.56  google-chrome-stable
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y vim build-essential patch libnss3 gconf2 libappindicator3-1 libasound2 libxss1 xdg-utils libgtk-3-0 libx11-xcb1 libxtst6 fonts-liberation lsb-release unzip libdrm2 libgbm1 --no-install-recommends &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* &&     curl -O https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb &&     dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb]: exit code: 1
ERROR: Service 'worker' failed to build : Build failed

試したこと: 1
sudo apt-get update -y 、
sudo apt-get install -y libu2f-udev、
sudo apt-get install -y libvulkan1 で、
however:... で無いと言われたパッケージをインストールしてみた後、
再度 docker-compose up app を実行してみた。
→ 結果、変わらず。
試したこと: 2
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y vim build-essential patch libnss3 gconf2 libappindicator3-1 libasound2 libxss1 xdg-utils libgtk-3-0 libx11-xcb1 libxtst6 fonts-liberation lsb-release unzip libdrm2 libgbm1 --no-install-recommends &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* &&     curl -O https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb &&     dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb]: exit code: 1

上記で [] 内の各処理を個別に実行してみた。全て問題が無さそうな、、、認識です。※WSLより実行。コンテナ外だから意味が無かった？

/bin/sh -c apt-get update　> apt のバージョンとヘルプが表示される。
apt-get install -y vim build-essential patch libnss3 gconf2 libappindicator3-1 libasound2 libxss1 xdg-utils libgtk-3-0 libx11-xcb1 libxtst6 fonts-liberation lsb-release unzip libdrm2 libgbm1 --no-install-recommends > 全てインストール成功
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* > 削除成功
curl -O https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb > ダウンロード成功
dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb > 実行成功


「試したこと２」からそれ以下のコマンドをDockerfileで見えません。このコマンドはどこに書かれる情報を付けられていただけますか。それに、「試したこと２」は　docker コンテナの中にお試ししましたか。ログみると、基本イメージには必要な依存関係がないそうです。ほかの基本イメージを使うのはいかがでしょうか。

@fastrack さん、コメント頂きありがとうございます。


「試したこと２」からそれ以下のコマンドをDockerfileで見えません。このコマンドはどこに書かれる情報を付けられていただけますか。>>
失礼しました。これは wsl から実行しています。




それに、「試したこと２」は　docker コンテナの中にお試ししましたか。>>
docker コンテナの中では試していません。なるほど、docker コンテナの中で実行する必要があるのですね、、、




ログみると、基本イメージには必要な依存関係がないそうです。ほかの基本イメージを使うのはいかがでしょうか。>>ありがとうございます。 docker-compose.yml の middlewares の image: alpine を変更した方がよいのでは、という事でしょうか。
こういった情報を参考に変更してみます。　https://zenn.dev/ken3pei/articles/1abbf7d974cf5d



使用している Docker イメージが5年前に更新されたものなので、OS の種類やバージョンが分かりませんが最新の Chrome に対応していない可能性があります。

@cubick さん、コメント頂きありがとうございます。そうなのですね、、dockerhubから検索できました。申し訳ございません。私の不注意なのですが、ご指摘のイメージ名が、サービス名称に関連しており、お手数をお掛けしてしまいますが、頂いたコメント内の該当部分を編集頂けますと幸いです。

docker-compose.yml 中の、app ブロックの dockerfile を見ると、参照しているのは、 Dockerfile.dev でした、、、
...
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev << ここを見落としていた

この Dockerfile.dev　に、エラーメッセージで出ていた足りていないライブラリを追加する事で、ひとまず冒頭のエラーの状態は脱しました。画面表示に至るまでには他にも色々とやりましたが、ひとまずこれでタイトルのエラーは脱しています。コメントを頂いた、@fastrack さん、@cubickさん、誠にありがとうございました。ご教示頂き、大変助かりました。（@cubickさん、コメント編集のお願いでお手数をおかけ致しました。ご対応頂き誠にありがとうございました。）
Dockerfile.dev
FROM ruby:2.6.3

# for npm install
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y default-mysql-client nodejs --no-install-recommends && \
    npm config set unsafe-perm=true && \
    npm install -g yarn

RUN gem install thor

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

ADD Gemfile Gemfile.lock /app/

# libu2f-udev libvulkan1 追加
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y vim build-essential patch libnss3 gconf2 libappindicator3-1 libasound2 libxss1 xdg-utils libgtk-3-0 libx11-xcb1 libxtst6 fonts-liberation lsb-release unzip libdrm2 libgbm1 libu2f-udev libvulkan1 --no-install-recommends && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    curl -O https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb


RUN CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE` && \
    curl -O https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver && \
    curl -O "https://noto-website-2.storage.googleapis.com/pkgs/NotoSansCJKjp-hinted.zip" && \
    unzip NotoSansCJKjp-hinted.zip && \
    mkdir -p /usr/share/fonts/noto && \
    cp -p *.otf /usr/share/fonts/noto/ && \
    fc-cache -fv

ENV ENTRYKIT_VERSION 0.4.0

RUN wget https://github.com/progrium/entrykit/releases/download/v${ENTRYKIT_VERSION}/entrykit_${ENTRYKIT_VERSION}_Linux_x86_64.tgz \
  && tar -xvzf entrykit_${ENTRYKIT_VERSION}_Linux_x86_64.tgz \
  && rm entrykit_${ENTRYKIT_VERSION}_Linux_x86_64.tgz \
  && mv entrykit /bin/entrykit \
  && chmod +x /bin/entrykit \
  && entrykit --symlink

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries

ENTRYPOINT [ \
  "prehook", "ruby -v", "--", \
  "prehook", "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid", "--", \
  "prehook", "bundle install -j3 --quiet --path vendor/bundle", "--", \
  "prehook", "yarn install", "--", \
  "switch", \
    "shell=/bin/bash", \
    "db=echo db start only", \
    "console=bundle exec rails console", \
    "bundle=bundle install", \
    "yarn=bundle exec bin/yarn", \
    "setup=infra/scripts/docker-setup.sh", \
    "setup_once=infra/scripts/docker-setup-once.sh", \
    "db_setup=bundle exec rails db:setup db:seed_fu", \
    "db_drop=bundle exec rails db:drop:_unsafe", \
    "db_create=bundle exec rails db:create", \
    "db_migrate=bundle exec rails db:migrate", \
    "db_seed=bundle exec rails db:seed_fu", "--"\
  ]

# vim:ft=dockerfile


